# How to pass "?" in URL android with id as my url is given below

Tags: java, android, retrofit, retrofit2

My URL

```
String BASE_URL = "http://74.207.233.160/api/v1/";
```

Here `17` is the id that I want to pass manually

My Interface is

```
public interface MyCandidateApi {

@GET("{user_id}")
Call<MyJobs> matchingcandidates(
        @Path(value = "user_id", encoded = true) String user_id,
        @Header("Authorization") String token
);
}
```

I am passing `user_id` as

```
Integer id = 17;
String user_id = "candidates?job="+id;
```

But when i run it the url is showing in this format
"http://74.207.233.160/api/v1/candidates%3Fjob=17"

Can u please help me to resolve it

Comment: FYI, `%3F` is the URL encoded form of `?`.

Comment: then i am not getting output

Comment: Hmm `encoded = true` should disable it from converting `?` to `%3F` as seen at [Path](https://square.github.io/retrofit/2.x/retrofit/index.html?retrofit2/http/Path.html). Can you show the other parts of your code?

Answer (score 0):

The string you have the is partially url encoded, try using [URLDecoder](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/net/URLDecoder.html).

```
String afterDecode = URLDecoder.decode(<your string>, "UTF-8");
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure about your use case, but Retrofit has ways to handle this that in my opinion seem better for this specific case.

I'd make the interface like so:

```
public interface MyCandidateApi {

  @GET("candidates")
  Call<MyJobs> matchingcandidates(
    @Query("job") int user_id,
    @Header("Authorization") String token
  );
}
```

Like this, `candidates` is added to the path automatically, as well as the query parameter `job`. Like this you don't need to worry about encoding the parameter or even converting it into a string. Retrofit does it for you.

This assumes you don't want to encode it at all. Judging from your question, that's the desired behavior.